# Get Size of ImageView in RemoteViews

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, remoteview

I am writing an Android AppWidget.  The layout for the widget contains a LinearLayout and, inside that, a number of ImageViews.  In the AppWidgetProvider OnUpdate method, I first create a RemoteViews for the layout ...

```
var rv = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.WidgetLayout);
```

... and, using that, I can set the bitmaps for each of the child ImageViews.

However, what I really want to do is to get the actual size of the ImageViews once layout is complete so that I can draw exactly sized images (probably via Bitmaps) into them.  I see no way to get the ImageView sizes via RemoteViews, nor any way to get to the underlying ImageView of a RemoteViews item.

Can I even do this?  Is it done in OnUpdate()?  If so, how?  If not, where should I be doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I even do this?

No. The rendering of the UI defined by the `RemoteViews` is handled by a separate app (home screen) in a separate process. You have no means of getting at Java objects from other processes, `Views` in particular.

Comment: Ah!  Now I get it.  Thanks for the info CW.

Answer (score 2):

You can get size of widget - approximate size of widget.
In layout, you can use "weights" - and if you know sizes of widget, and weights of images - you can approximately calculate sizes of images.
I am using such approach to make proper bitmaps.
One of problems - is different devices lie differently.
One of my bitmaps has next weights - 0.6 of width, and 0.15 of height.

```
        SetTitleButton( context,  views, (int) (w*0.6),   (int)(h*0.15*coefficient));
```

where coefficient  is attempt to compensate different "lie" and user can modify it to fit...

w and h - are size of widget.

```
Bundle awo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions( appWidgetId);
    int h=awo.getInt("appWidgetMaxHeight");
    int w=awo.getInt("appWidgetMaxWidth");
```

Comment: To avoid hard-coded string, I suggest using `AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT` and `AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH` instead.

Comment: Where do you place this code?